# In Flink, how can I access the Key when applying a Process Function on a Keyed Stream?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In Flink, I have a keyed stream to which I am applying a Process Function.

```
myDataStream
  .keyBy(new MyKeySelector())
  .process(new FooBarProcessFunction())
```

My Key Selector looks something like this...

```
public class MyKeySelector implements KeySelector<FooBar, FooKey>

public FooKey getKey (FooBar value) {
   return new FooKey (value);
}
```

And FooBarProcessFunction looks something like this...

```
public class FooBarProcessFunction extends ProcessFunction<FooBar, TransformedFooBar> {

    public void processElement(FooBar newFooBar, Context ctx, Collector<FooBar> out) {
        //do something with newFooBar
        // *****but I also want to know the Key (FooKey) here***** 
    }
}
```

In FooBarProcessFunction, I would like to obtain the Key which was created by MyKeySelector's getKey method.  Is that doable?

At present, I am using a workaround wherein I essentially recreate the Key in the processElement function.  But it would be ideal if I can avoid doing so.

Comment: Sorry, but while the key is obviously known to the Flink runtime, it is not made available via the API.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access to the key from a process function, you should use `KeyedProcessFunction`

Your example become:

```
public class FooBarProcessFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<FooKey, FooBar, TransformedFooBar> {

    public void processElement(FooBar newFooBar, Context ctx, Collector<FooBar> out) {
        //do something with newFooBar
        // *****but I also want to know the Key (FooKey) here***** 
        ctx.getCurrentKey
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can get the key if you window your keyed stream and apply a `ProcessWindowFunction<IN, OUT, KEY, W extends Window>`.

There are some examples of [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#keyed-vs-non-keyed-windows) on the Apache flink docs. Quick note that a `ProcessWindowFunction` is inefficient and should be combined with a `ReduceFunction`, `AggregateFunction`, or `FoldFunction`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Inside onTimer or processElement function:

```
String dataId = (String) context.getCurrentKey();
```